# jquery 1.4.2 working for iCheckBox and not jquery 1.6

Tags: version, compatibility, jquery-1.6

I am using [this](http://brynmosher.com/jquery.iCheckbox/example.html) jquery plugin for Apple like checkbox button.

However when I use jquery version 1.4.2 it works perfectly but when I try to use jquery version 1.6. that plugin doesn't work.

I tried debugging javascript using IE9 developer toolbar but it is not throwing any error.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: got it working in FF4 as well now, see this: [jQuery 1.6: backgroundPosition vs backgroundPositionX and FF4 compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322347)

Got it working with jQuery 1.6.x and 1.5.x
(in Safari and Chrome on Mac, not working in FF4/Mac)

There were two problems with the original code, one making it incompatible with jQuery 1.5 and 1.6 and one making it incompatible with jQuery 1.6.

The first problem was the use of the

```
backgroundPosition property
```

in the animate calls, they needed to be changed into the

```
backgroundPositionX property
```

for jQuery 1.5 and 1.6

The second problem was the check for whether the checkbox is checked or not.
In jQuery 1.4 and 1.5 this could be done with

```
if ( $(this).attr('checked') == true )
```

but in jQuery 1.6 this does not work, it need to be changed into

```
if ( $(this).is(':checked') )
```

The code found here works for jQuery 1.6: http://jsfiddle.net/mikkelbreum/HAGMp/

Comment: Hey...That is nice...I tried it in firefox 4 it is not sliding thought checkbox's value is changing but in Safari it is working.

Comment: yes I found out as well it's not working in FF4, looking into that at the moment.. not sure what's happening there, firebug is giving wierd messages about 'attempt to run compiles script on closed scope' that I do not understand.. and also that it fails to load a resource..

Comment: I updated the jsfiddle link, the server where the images was stores was no longer responding, so i changed to another server.

Comment: To make it work in FF4 change the animate lines to: animate({backgroundPosition: '0px'}) and animate({backgroundPosition: settings.switch_swing+'px'} see: jsfiddle.net/mikkelbreum/uHkE5

Answer (score 0):

Try updating to jQuery 1.6.1. With 1.6, they broke backwards compatibility with `.attr()` (which breaks many plugins) but the 1.6.1 update [addresses this](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/05/12/jquery-1-6-1-released/).

Comment: You should probably file a report with the developer then. There's a ticket open that is reporting issues with [jQuery > 1.4.2](http://code.google.com/p/icheckbox/issues/detail?id=4).

Comment: I have the same problem. the plugin code is fairly short.. if the developer does not have time to fix it, it should be an easy task for another developer. I'll have a look at it.

Comment: got it working in FF4, but in a wierd way, see edit note in my answer