# jQuery 1.6: backgroundPosition vs backgroundPositionX and FF4 compatibility

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, firefox4, background-position

In an attempt to upgrade the jQuery plugin 'iCheckbox' (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032538/) to work above jQuery 1.4.4 I found out that the use of

```
 animate({backgroundPosition:'10px 0px'})
```

needed to be changed to

```
animate({backgroundPositionX: '10px', backgroundPositionY:  '0px'})
```

as only properties with one parameter should be used. So far, this makes sense, but wait.. while it's working fine in Safari and Chrome, it's not working in FF4 (all on Mac)..

So i tried this and that and finally found out that if I change it to

```
animate({backgroundPosition: '10px'})
```

It works everywhere!
But what's going on here? Now that I just give one parameter, it works, but I'm not specifying if it's for X or Y axis (so it defaults to X axis it seems.. but what if I want it to work on Y axis?)

This seems wierd, and my solutions here can't be the correct way of doing it.. so I need some advice:

What's going on?

How should background position be animated using jQuery 1.4 - 1.6 so that it works across browsers?

Comment: if you feel like it, please quickly check if the button works and slides in IE7,8,9 and answer in comments here? test: http://jsfiddle.net/mikkelbreum/uHkE5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, JQuery is unable to animate two values at the same time, thus you saw that inputting two values for `backgroundPosition` did not work at all. Also note that for `px` values, the [JQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) encourages you to *not* write the `px`.

Secondly, `backgroundPositionX` and `backgroundPositionY` are *non-standard* CSS properties only supported in a few browsers, most notably IE and recently Webkit, which is why you will find it does not work in FF or Opera. ([See here](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/background-position-x-y).)

I have found that mixing JQuery's `animate` and CSS transitions works to animate a background image on one axis in most browsers. I will quote from my answer to another question ( [jQuery.animate background-position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7719214/jquery-animate-background-position/8026020)):

> Use JQuery's `.animate()` and `backgroundPositionX` and `Y` separately
>   for IE (this will work with the latest JQuery). Then in browsers that
>   [support CSS transitions](http://caniuse.com/css-transitions) (nearly everything besides IE), use
>   `.css()` instead of `.animate()` to change the background position and set
>   a CSS transition in your stylesheet.
>
> You'll be covering most browsers with the above, but it may not be AS
>   compatible as just using a plugin. See it at work here:
>   http://jsfiddle.net/lucylou/dVpjh/

Answer (score 0):

According to:
http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_background-position.asp

"If you only specify one value, the other value will be 50%. You can mix % and positions"