# Background Position animation in jQuery not working in Firefox

Tags: jquery

I am working on a wesbsite here: http://www.benjaminpotter.org/portfolio2/

Look at the loading splash, it looks all good but not in Firefox. Do you know why background positions being animated in jquery don't work in Firefox? Have a look at the script attached to it called animate [here](http://www.benjaminpotter.org/portfolio2/js/animate.js).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted by *dzejkej*, separate values for background-position are not part of the standard and not supported by Firefox. As noted on the [jQuery `animate()` page](http://api.jquery.com/animate/):

> All animated properties should be animated to a single numeric value

And that means that `background-position` doesn't qualify, as it requires two values, x pos and y pos.

You will have to use an animation plugin. Unfortunately, at the moment the jQuery plugins site is down, so I have provided a version that works in Firefox here:

```
/** jquery.bgpos.js
 * @author Alexander Farkas
 * v. 1.02
 */
(function($) {
    $.extend($.fx.step,{
        backgroundPosition: function(fx) {
            if (fx.state === 0 && typeof fx.end == 'string') {
                var start = $.curCSS(fx.elem,'backgroundPosition');
                start = toArray(start);
                fx.start = [start[0],start[2]];
                var end = toArray(fx.end);
                fx.end = [end[0],end[2]];
                fx.unit = [end[1],end[3]];
            }
            var nowPosX = [];
            nowPosX[0] = ((fx.end[0] - fx.start[0]) * fx.pos) + fx.start[0] + fx.unit[0];
            nowPosX[1] = ((fx.end[1] - fx.start[1]) * fx.pos) + fx.start[1] + fx.unit[1];
            fx.elem.style.backgroundPosition = nowPosX[0]+' '+nowPosX[1];

           function toArray(strg){
               strg = strg.replace(/left|top/g,'0px');
               strg = strg.replace(/right|bottom/g,'100%');
               strg = strg.replace(/([0-9\.]+)(\s|\)|$)/g,"$1px$2");
               var res = strg.match(/(-?[0-9\.]+)(px|\%|em|pt)\s(-?[0-9\.]+)(px|\%|em|pt)/);
               return [parseFloat(res[1],10),res[2],parseFloat(res[3],10),res[4]];
           }
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Please see [this page](http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/jquery-bg-image-animations) for reference on it's use.

Answer (score 0):

`background-position-x` is non standard CSS property and it is not supported by Firefox.

See:

- http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/background-position-x-y
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/8175460/1011582

Answer (score 0):

I got mine working with better and simple solution

First install jquery migration

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/#readme

The $.browser property allows you to target browsers you want to apply your style into

In this case for background-position can be changed to property supported backgroundPosition

Available flags are
 - webkit
 - safari
 - opera
 - msie (for IE)
 - mozilla

Example for IE or Firefox

```
if ( $.browser.msie || $.browser.mozilla) {
            $(".element").css('backgroundPosition', position + "px 0");                
}
```

for chrome

```
if ( $.browser.webkit) {
            $(".element").css('backgroundPosition', position + "px 0");                
}
```