# How can I make this div slide up and down hover effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a `<div>` animation very much like this site: http://www.weareinstrument.com/about/. When you hover over the darker grey boxes and the images at the bottom of the screen they seem to slide up and down depending if you're hovering them. I can't seem to find the jQuery in the source code for it. Can anyone inform me on how it would be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a possible way to achieve this. Let's say the `div` showing by default has class `default` and the one that shows on hover has class `onhover`.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jPneT/1/

```
$('.up-down').mouseover(function(){
    $('.default').stop().animate({
        height: 0    
    }, 200);                        
}).mouseout(function(){
    $('.default').stop().animate({
        height: 200 
    }, 200)    
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a css sprite and animate `background-position`. It won't work in Firefox, so you need to use this plugin suggested here [Background Position animation in jQuery not working in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8378696/background-position-animation-in-jquery-not-working-in-firefox).
Good thing about this solution is that you can easily fallback to css in case JS is disabled.

**html:**

```
<div id="img"></div>
```

**css**

```
#img {
    height: 256px;
    width: 256px;
    background: url(http://i42.tinypic.com/auwns0.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;
}

/* Fallback */
#nojs #img:hover { background-position: 0 -256px; }
```

**jQ:**

```
$('#img').hover(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({'background-position': '0 -256px'});
}, function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({'background-position': '0 0'});
});
```

**Example:**

http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/T2JXn/9/

Answer (score 1):

I did not search for the code on the website you have mentioned, but you could use something like this:

```
<div id="foo">
    <div id="onMouseIn" style="display:none"><img src="inPicture"/></div>
    <div id="onMouseOut"><img src="outPicture"/></div>   
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#foo').hover(function(){
        //This is onMouseIn event
        $('#onMouseIn').slideDown(150);
        $('#onMouseOut').slideUp(150);
    }, 
    function(){
        //This is onMouseOut event
        $('#onMouseOut').slideDown(150);
        $('#onMouseIn').slideUp(150);
    });
});
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/aWdBT/27/) is the fiddle.

Comment: In your example, the `e` in `function(e)` is totally superfluous.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a tutorial you might like:

http://buildinternet.com/2009/03/sliding-boxes-and-captions-with-jquery/