# Scroll to hidden element

Tags: jquery, google-maps, smooth-scrolling

This should work like Google Maps marker. When you click on some element, it will smoothly animate to marker (coords).

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="inner">
        <div id="marker"><!-- --></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="overflow">Hover to disable overflow</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#wrapper {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 3px solid #999;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 50px auto 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

#inner {
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    background: url("http://i50.tinypic.com/25aq6iu.jpg") no-repeat 0 0 #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: -150px;
    left: -200px;
}

#marker {
    width: 20px;
    height: 26px;
    background: url("http://i50.tinypic.com/29kujo3.png") no-repeat 0 0 transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: 123px;
    left: 153px;
}

.overflow {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #ccc;
    margin: 20px auto 0;
    padding: 10px;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

How to make it work?

Here is fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/xRbR8/1/

Answer (score 0):

you must animate the background-position of #inner and the left/top of #marker .

Take a look at [Background Position animation in jQuery not working in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8378696/background-position-animation-in-jquery-not-working-in-firefox) for a solution for animating a background-position