# Jquery animation doesn't animate

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I want to animate a picture with jQuery. I have this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".label").delay(2000).animate({backgroundPositionX:"0px",backgroundPositionY:"30px"},10000,linear);
$(".label").animate({backgroundPositionX: "-70px" ,backgroundPositionY:"30px"},10000,linear);
$(".label").animate({backgroundPositionX: "-140px" ,backgroundPositionY:"30px"},10000,linear);
```

but the animation doesn't work. Any idea what is going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

This [SO question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8175460/978264) will help. `backgroundPositionX` and `backgroundPositionY` are non standard and won't work in all browsers.

Comment: I have tried with all browsers with no result. I will try to pass only one parameter for background position. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I edited my code to this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".label").delay(2000).css({
   "backgroundPositionX": "0px",
    "backgroundPositionY": "30px"
  }, 5000, 'linear');
  $(".label").animate({
    "backgroundPositionX": "-70px",
   "backgroundPositionY": "30px"
  }, 5000, 'linear');
  $(".label").animate({
    "backgroundPositionX": "-140px",
    "backgroundPositionY": "30px"
  }, 5000, 'linear');
});
```

and it works for **Chrome**.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".label").delay(2000).animate({
    backgroundPositionX: "0px",
    backgroundPositionY: "30px"
  }, 10000, 'linear');
  $(".label").animate({
   backgroundPositionX: "-70px",
   backgroundPositionY: "30px"
  }, 10000, 'linear');
  $(".label").animate({
    backgroundPositionX: "-140px",
    backgroundPositionY: "30px"
  }, 10000, 'linear');
});
```

A [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dcsM9/2/)