# Bootstrap carousel slide function. Things won't work in Mozilla

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-animate, carousel, mozilla

I've got this code:

```
var $carousel = $('#carousel-showcase');
$carousel.carousel();

$carousel.bind('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {

  setTimeout( function(){
    var left = $carousel.find('.item.active.left');
    var right = $carousel.find('.item.active.right');
    if(left.length > 0) {
    $("#wrap").animate({
        backgroundPositionX: '+=50%'
    },0);
    }
    else if(right.length > 0) {
    $("#wrap").animate({
        backgroundPositionX: '-=50%'
    },0);
    }
  }, 500);
});
```

to fire off an animate function on slide change in the bootstrap 3 carousel.  Everything works fine in Chrome, however it doesn't work in Mozilla. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

backgroundPositionX (or Y) works only in webkit or IE ([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8175460/1919627)). You'll have to use the css function for all other browsers:

```
$("#wrap").css('backgroundPosition','45% 0%');
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ringstaff/L4U4A/11/) for an example.